# How do amino acids become attached to tRNA?

Tags: molecular-genetics, rna, translation

Is there a protein that catalyzes this or does it happen spontaneously?

In which part of the cell does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process to which you refer is called *tRNA charging* and is catalyzed in the cytosol by a class of enzymes called [aminoacyl tRNA synthetases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aminoacyl_tRNA_synthetase).

Comment: ...and it happens in the cytosol.

Comment: @ohcanada, sorry for blowing off your suggested edit. I should have given the original question and your suggestion more consideration.